# How to list posts from a plugin taxonomy?

Tags: php, query-posts, functions

I would like to query posts from a taxonomy created by a plugin (WP Business Directory Manager). How would I do this? I want the query to create html listing of the posts and allow me to list a certain amount, show the associated image to the posts, and a small excerpt.

Some examples on wp stack exchange seem like they would help, but might be different in my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: query posts that have a specific taxonomy term associated with them, or posts that have at any/at least one term from that taxonomy associated with them?

Comment: Yes sorry for leaving that piece of info out. The taxonomy name is wpbdm-category and the post-type is wpbdm-directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query by taxonomy you need to know its `query_var` that is used in its [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) call. It defaults to taxonomy name so usually equal to that.

Then you use that info in query argument:

```
query_posts( array( 'query_var' => 'term' ) );
```

See [Querying by taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy) in Codex.

It is hard to suggest more without specifics of your taxonomy and where you need it done (template, standalone function, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the name of the taxonomy is wpbdm-category and the post type is wpbdm-directory. The plugin that created these is WP Business Directory Manager (might be helpful).

Comment: i think it's better if you use `'post_type' => 'wpbdm-directory'` in this case.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Is there a way to query the post content/excerpts? I want to replicate the listings in the directory and list them on the homepage. Can this be done?